# how to view user data in codeigniter using 3 times log out my data is not visible

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new in PHP and Codeigniter, by the way how to update database table when session in CI is expired and where I can put the code? I use uniqid in database, it's called token. here is my login tableusername, password, level, token, last_login, exp_time. and I want to change value token=null when session in Codeigniter is expired.

Comment: This question may be best suited on http://forum.codeigniter.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think you're approaching this the wrong way. Sessions can expire passively, so your user DB would not be up to date.

You could use Codeigniter's option to store session data in your MySQL database and check against those entries.

Comment: Hi pascal 

 am clicked log out button in  3 times ,again login into 4th time ,my data is not vissible,once clear cache